# Automatically turn on keyboard backlit on Asus tuf505dt with Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: keyboard, 20.04, laptop, asus

My asus tuf 505dt laptop has a backlit keyboard, but it doesn't start on Ubuntu. I have dual boot with Ubuntu 20.04.

On Windows I can manually turn it on using the Asus software provided. But I was wondering how I can do that on Ubuntu. I once saw a terminal command that turned it on, but since then I can't find that anymore. Also that command wasn't permanent, it went back to the previous state after restarting. Is there a way I can make it always turn on at startup?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution, posting it here in case someone needs it later.

```
sudo /etc/acpi/asus-keyboard-backlight.sh
```

This will turn the backlight on.
To make it automatic on startup, copy this script to /etc/init.d and make it executable.

Answer (score 0):

In Linux with KDE go to **System Settings > Power Management > Energy Saving > Keyboard backlight <kbd>On</kbd>**

That's all without any script.

Comment: With the ASUS Tuf Dash F15 I can now run settings, power and have a slider setting how bright I want the keyboard background to be in Ubuntu 20.04